# Django rest framework, redirect after making post

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an API build with the Django rest framework.

There is a post where a user inputs some data, And, a retrieve method in my view that renders an HTML page based on the data from the post.

There's a field in the post called 'mission_name' which is a primary key so when a user inserts the mission name to the end of the URL line it runs the retrieve method.

mission name : testredirect

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/twosecondgdt/testredirect/`  Will open the page.

How do I redirect the retrieve method upon a successful post?

```py
# views.py

from __future__ import absolute_import

from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from Project_Level.database_consts import THREE_POINTS_TRINAGULATION
from Project_Level.postgres_queries import HTMLFileInteractionWithDB
from .serializers import PointsSerializer
from .models import Points

from Project_Level.base_objects import GeoPoint
from .second_GDT_finding.app import MainApp


class PointsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # Return all missions ordered by id, reversed.
    queryset = Points.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = PointsSerializer

    data = queryset[0]
    serialized_data = PointsSerializer(data, many=False)
    points = list(serialized_data.data.values())

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        mission_name = self.points[1]

        assign_gdt = GeoPoint(lat=self.points[2], long=self.points[3])
        gdt1 = [assign_gdt.get_lat(), assign_gdt.get_long()]

        assign_uav = GeoPoint(lat=self.points[4], long=self.points[5], elevation=self.points[6])
        uav = [assign_uav.get_lat(), assign_uav.get_long(), assign_uav.get_elevation()]

        area_name = f"'{self.points[-2]}'"

        try:
            # Check if a file already exists in the DB.
            HTMLFileInteractionWithDB.table = THREE_POINTS_TRINAGULATION
            openfile = HTMLFileInteractionWithDB.return_file_from_db(mission_name=mission_name)
            print('File was fetched from DB')
            return render(request, openfile)
        except:
            # If no map was plotted, create a new one.
            main = MainApp.run(gdt1=gdt1, uav=uav, mission_name=mission_name, area=area_name)
            print('New file created')
            return render(request, main)
```

Comment: unrelated, but 1/ `points = list(serialized_data.data.values())` will only be executed once on process startup, so you will get stale data, and 2/ your bare `except` clause is an antipattern - only put the single line that may raise, and only catch the specific exception that indicates that a file doesn't already exists.

Comment: wrt/ "how tp redirect", your question is unclear - where do you actually want to redirect from, and where do you want to redirect to ? (note that you don't "redirect a method" - you redirect to an url).